# I don't understand the cache of Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, cdn, amazonsellercentral

I have a managed webserver with ~ 4000 images with 7,4 GB and I've enabled Cloudflare CDN for it.

I've run a curl script to download all images. I expected that the image will be put into Cloudflare (free plan) cache afterwards, but when I download them again via curl, it's still very slow. I can also see in the webinterface, that most requests are not cached.

[image]

Then I've run curl with `-I` to check the headers and I run it after a few minutes again and the result is totally different

```
$ cat curl-output-headers.txt | grep 'cf-cache-status: REVALIDATED'|wc
    303     606    9090
$ cat curl-output-headers.txt | grep 'cf-cache-status: MISS'|wc
    549    1098   12627
$ cat curl-output-headers.txt | grep 'cf-cache-status: HIT'|wc
   3267    6534   71874

#a few minutes later

$ cat curl-output-headers2.txt | grep 'cf-cache-status: HIT'|wc
    457     914   10054
$ cat curl-output-headers2.txt | grep 'cf-cache-status: MISS'|wc
   2428    4856   55844
$ cat curl-output-headers2.txt | grep 'cf-cache-status: REVALIDATED'|wc
   1234    2468   37020
```

When I download the files via GET, it takes ~15 minutes.

A short summary what I try to do: do a bulk upload to amazon seller via an excel file.
It doesn't work because amazon tries to download too much images at the same time, even 100 rows.
In my first attempt I was using images URLs by the manufacturer webserver. If I download them manually, it takes 7 minutes, but for amazon still to slow (but I guess amazon is downloading them in parallel, not like me in serial via curl).

Hoever, my idea was to use a CDN, but somehow it become even worse but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

I have also a VPS with a dedicated IP, maybe I should use that server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudflare doesn't guarantee every server response will always be cached, especially for a free account. With a free account they may not cache something until many requests for that resource start coming in.

Also, by default your Cloudflare account will have a different cache on each [Cloudflare edge location](https://www.cloudflare.com/network/), which means if requests end up routed to different edge locations the cache will be different.

You would need to enable [Tiered Caching](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/tiered-cache/) to fix the "multiple caches per edge" issue. And you would need to enable [Cache Reserve](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cache-reserve/) to guarantee your server response is always cached.

Comment: Thank you, I've enabled Tiered Caching and also Cache Reserve (paid for that now).
Before I've setup a page rule wich: Edge Cache TTL: a month, for the images. I guess I can keep that settingm right?

Comment: I've enabled "Smart Tiered Caching Topology" - is that what you're talking about? I think the other values I can only set with Enterprise plan.

Comment: Do I need to wait some time? After enabling "Smart Tiered Caching Topology" and Cache Reserve, I've started to download 200 images via curl. First 1st time it took 90 seconds, 2nd time it took 36s, then 27s, then 23s and the 5th and 6th time it was 20s. Even after second time `curl -I` showed `cf-cache-status: HIT` for all execpt one of the 200 images. I don't understand why the time was still reducing afterwards each time. And why the images from original manufacturer webspace just take 17s with an appache server? I was expecting to be faster then the manufacturer.

Comment: 7th test with sequential download, cloudfalre has reached now 18 seconds, that's good. I've wrote a nodejs app to download in parallel, from manufacturer it takes 13 seconds, from cloudflare 8 seconds. That's great. Thank you!

Comment: None of the things I told you require an enterprise plan. Tiered caching is available on the free plan. Cache Reserve is a usage-based paid addon to any plan.